# Странное поведение кастомного адаптера при повороте экрана

Tags: java, android, счетчики

Задача написать `listView` с хронометрами и при повороте сохранять состояние каждого таймера. Но когда запускаю таймер/таймеры и поворачиваю экран, с какого бы я таймера не начал, начинает отчет первый элемент списка. Он формально не запущен, но отчет начинает. 
Вот фрагмент кода:

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

    ListView listView;
    MyAdapter myAdapter;
    private final int LOADER_ID =1;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Bundle bundle;
    List<Long> lastPauseList;
    List<Integer> positionnList;
    List<Boolean> startList;
    List<Long> basesList;
    List<Long> tested;
    List<Long> elapsed;
    List<Tracker> trackerList;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bundle = savedInstanceState;
        db = RemindMe.db;
        trackerList = Tracker.getListAll(db);
        String[] from = {Tracker.COL_NAME,Tracker.COL_ELAPSED_TIME};
        int[]to={R.id.row_name,R.id.row_chronometer};
        startList = new ArrayList<Boolean>(trackerList.size());
        lastPauseList = new ArrayList<Long>(trackerList.size());
        for (int i = 0; i <trackerList.size() ; i++) {
            startList.add(false);
            lastPauseList.add((long)0);
        }
        if(bundle!=null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < trackerList.size(); i++) {
                startList.set(i,savedInstanceState.getBoolean("start " + i));
                lastPauseList.set(i,bundle.getLong("lastPause "+i));



                Log.d("myTag", "OnCreate-----------------------------------------");
                Log.d("myTag", "position " + i);
                Log.d("myTag", "elapsedTime "+ getTime(savedInstanceState.getLong("elapsedTime " + i)));
                Log.d("myTag", "base " + getTime(savedInstanceState.getLong("base " + i)));
                Log.d("myTag", "lastPause "+ getTime(savedInstanceState.getLong("lastPause "+i)));
                Log.d("myTag", "start "+ savedInstanceState.getBoolean("start " + i));
                Log.d("myTag", "------------------------------------------end onCreate");
            }
        }
        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this,R.layout.list_item, Tracker.getAll(db),from,to,0);
        listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID,null,this);


    }
    public void onCLick(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,AddTrack.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        return new TrackLoader(this,db);

    }
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        myAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

    }

    static class TrackLoader extends CursorLoader {
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        public TrackLoader(Context context,SQLiteDatabase db){
            super(context);
            this.db = db;
        }
        @Override
        public Cursor loadInBackground() {
            return Tracker.getAll(db);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        for (int i = 0; i <elapsed.size() ; i++) {
            if(basesList.get(i)>1000){
                outState.putLong("elapsedTime " + i, elapsed.get(i));
            }
            outState.putLong("base "+i,basesList.get(i));
            outState.putLong("lastPause "+i,lastPauseList.get(i));
            outState.putBoolean("start " + i, startList.get(i));



            Log.d("myTag", "OnSavedInstanceState-----------------------------------------");
            Log.d("myTag", "position " + i);
            Log.d("myTag", "elapsedTime " + getTime(outState.getLong("elapsedTime "+i)));
            Log.d("myTag", "base "+ getTime(outState.getLong("base "+i)));
            Log.d("myTag", "lastPause "+ getTime(outState.getLong("lastPause "+i)));
            Log.d("myTag", "start "+ outState.getBoolean("start " + i));
            Log.d("myTag","------------------------------------------end onSavedInstanceState");
        }

    }
    String getTime(long time){
        int hours = (int)(time/3600000);
        int minutes = (int)(time -hours*3600000)/60000;
        int seconds = (int)(time-hours*3600000-minutes*60000)/1000;
        String hour = (hours<9?"0"+hours:hours).toString();
        String min = (minutes<9?"0"+minutes:minutes).toString();
        String sec = (seconds<9?"0"+seconds:seconds).toString();
        return ""+hour+":"+min+":"+sec;
    }

    public class MyAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

        Context context;
        int resorceID;

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        public MyAdapter(Context context,int resourceID,Cursor c,String[] from,int[]to,int flags){
            super(context,resourceID,c,from,to,flags);
            this.context=context;
            this.resorceID =resourceID;
            elapsed = new ArrayList<Long>(trackerList.size());
            basesList = new ArrayList<Long>(trackerList.size());
            for (int i = 0; i <trackerList.size() ; i++) {
                elapsed.add((long) 0);
                basesList.add((long)0);
            }

        }
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

            View row = convertView;
            TrackHolder holder=null;
            final Tracker tracker = trackerList.get(position);
            final long[] lastPause = new long[1];
            long elapsedTime;
            final long base;
            boolean bundleIsItStart;

            if(row==null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(resorceID,parent,false);
                holder = new TrackHolder();
                holder.name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.row_name);
                holder.chronometer = (Chronometer)row.findViewById(R.id.row_chronometer);
                holder.start = (Button)row.findViewById(R.id.btStart);
                holder.stop = (Button)row.findViewById(R.id.btStop);
                row.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (TrackHolder)row.getTag();
            }
            if(!trackerList.isEmpty()) {

                final TrackHolder finalHolder = holder;
                holder.start.setEnabled(true);
                holder.stop.setEnabled(false);

                if(bundle!=null){

                    holder.name.setText(tracker.getName());
                    elapsedTime = bundle.getLong("elapsedTime "+position);//получеаем значение прошедшего времени после поворота экрана
                    base = bundle.getLong("base " + position);//получаем, сохраненную на пред экране.
                    lastPause[0]=bundle.getLong("lastPause " + position);//получаем разницу во времени(паузу) с SavedInstanceState
                    bundleIsItStart=bundle.getBoolean("start " + position);//получаем статус: запущен/остановлен

                    basesList.set(position,base);

                    if(elapsedTime>elapsed.get(position))//если время, полученое после поворота больше, которое насчитает в onTick, запишется в список, но такого никогда не будет
                        elapsed.set(position, elapsedTime);
                    if(startList.get(position)==bundleIsItStart)//по аналогии как выше, если если текущий элемент == статусу, пишем в список статус, иначе элемент остается в списке
                        startList.set(position,bundleIsItStart);
                    if(lastPauseList.get(position)>lastPause[0])
                        lastPauseList.set(position,lastPause[0]);

                    if(bundleIsItStart){
                        holder.stop.setEnabled(true);
                        holder.start.setEnabled(false);
                            holder.chronometer.setBase(base);
                            holder.chronometer.start();
                    }
                    if(!bundleIsItStart && base>1000){
                        holder.chronometer.setBase(base+(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()-base+lastPause[0]));
                        holder.stop.setEnabled(false);
                        holder.start.setEnabled(true);
                    }

                }else{

                    holder.name.setText(tracker.getName());
                    holder.start.setEnabled(true);
                    holder.stop.setEnabled(false);
                }
                holder.start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        finalHolder.chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + lastPause[0]);
                        finalHolder.chronometer.start();
                        finalHolder.stop.setEnabled(true);
                        finalHolder.start.setEnabled(false);
                        basesList.set(position, finalHolder.chronometer.getBase());
                        startList.set(position,true);
                    }
                });
                holder.stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        lastPause[0]=finalHolder.chronometer.getBase()-SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                        finalHolder.chronometer.stop();
                        finalHolder.start.setEnabled(true);
                        finalHolder.stop.setEnabled(false);
                        lastPauseList.set(position,lastPause[0]);
                        startList.set(position,false);
                    }
                });
                holder.chronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
                        elapsed.set(position, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - finalHolder.chronometer.getBase());
                        Log.d("myTag", "elapsedTime = " + getTime(elapsed.get(position)) + " position = " + position);
                }
                });
            }

            return row;
        }
        String getTime(long time){
            int hours = (int)(time/3600000);
            int minutes = (int)(time -hours*3600000)/60000;
            int seconds = (int)(time-hours*3600000-minutes*60000)/1000;
            String hour = (hours<9?"0"+hours:hours).toString();
            String min = (minutes<9?"0"+minutes:minutes).toString();
            String sec = (seconds<9?"0"+seconds:seconds).toString();
            return ""+hour+":"+min+":"+sec;
        }
        class TrackHolder{
            TextView name;
            Chronometer chronometer;
            Button start,stop;
        }
    }

}
```

Дебажил много раз, вот после этой строки, допустим на 2 элементе, мы заходим в 
`onTick` и там, если навести курсор в дебаг-режиме на `position`, он показывает 0 элемент и пишет `elapsedTime`. Я убирал метод `onTick`, но все равно первый элемент отсчитывает время.

```
if(bundleIsItStart){
                    holder.stop.setEnabled(true);
                    holder.start.setEnabled(false);
                    holder.chronometer.setBase(base); --- после нее
                    holder.chronometer.start();
                }
```

Comment: Этой части кода недостаточно , чтобы понять логику работы при повороте ,но видимо position тоже нужно нужно сохранять в bundle , чтобы он пережил поворот , а не инициализировался заново при перестарте активти

Comment: вообще не понятно, как вы обрабатываете сохранение состояний.

Comment: @pavlofff 
Я добавил весь код класса, мне кажется с сохранением данных нет проблем, и я использую списки, то есть я записываю данные в них по индкесу равному позицию, потом вытягиваю данные из нужного списка для нужной позиции

Comment: при повороте экрана, активити уничтожается и создается заново. Так вот, как вы восстанавливаете данные таймеров ?

Comment: @aratj Вы наверно невнимательно просмотрели код, там есть нужный метод onSavedInstanceState, вытягиваю первую половину данных я в onCreate(), другую половину напрямую в кастомном адаптере, почему там? вытягивается в зависимости от position, нужкому итему, нужные данны

Comment: Для этой задачи может стоит перенести логику списка в фрагмент?Поскольку здесь в основном работа со счетчиками и визуального мало, то `setRetainInstance(true)`как раз для таких случаев и создан.

Answer (score 0):

Отключите пересоздание активити при перевороте. Возможно активити пересоздается(если вы не отключили) и заново вызывается ваш код.

```
<activity
    android:name="Ваша активити"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize"
    ...
</activity>
```

Comment: Активити должно пересоздаваться, не давайте плохих советов

Comment: @DeKaNszn а зачем пересоздавать активность если допустим приложение работает только в ландшафте и использует только одни размеры? Это не всегда плохой совет.

Comment: @Сергей сталкивались с устройствами типа asus padfone?

Comment: на прямую нет, но у меня в консоли гугла, этих азусов полно и никто не жаловался на приложение с таким манифестом.